# How do I enforce minimum requirements for my iOS app?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that requires at least an iPad with iOS 5.  I don't even want people who have older devices (and hence no gamekit) to be even able to download the app -- it will not run.

Is there a way to enforce this in the app store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum iOS version supported by an app is determined by the `Deployment Target` setting in its build target. Set this to `5.0`.

To restrict the app to the iPad, set its `Devices` setting to "iPad" rather than "Universal".